# Xamarin Forms Android push notifications "Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets."

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to setup push notifications on a Xamarin.Forms Android app following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#configure-android-manifest) tutorial and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-azurenotificationhub/) sample. My AndroidManifest.xml, FirebaseService.cs and MainActivity.cs are basically the same as the sample. When I fire up the Android Emulator and do a Test Send from Azure Notification Hubs I get: "Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets." Is that tutorial outdated?

Comment: If you have access to a real device try running your app there and see if you have other results.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me get an error message: "Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver> cannot be instantiated'" I need to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used a real device to debug the application and I got an error message: "Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver> cannot be instantiated'"

This was due to my code shrinker (ProGuard/R8) missing some configurations. Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows) article I created a proguard.cfg file and added this:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

I tried a Test Send from Azure Notification Hubs and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for following up and providing what worked! I'm glad you got it working. :)

Comment: @Luis Do you happen to remember what clases/libraries you needed to "keep" to make this work ? I am getting the same error and have tried multiple variations of the class names and it still keeps failing

Comment: Thanks! I've been using the [FirebasePushNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) in Xamarin.Forms and this resolved my problem.