# Didn't find class "com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, onesignal

I'm new to Xamarin and trying to get OneSignal push notifications working in Android. When running the emulator and I fire a push notification from OneSignal, it comes through successfully on the emulator.  However, when I deploy the app via Play Store, and I have the app open, firing a push notification crashes the app with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars-Bl5_t81uXklo5mpGZRvJcw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars-Bl5_t81uXklo5mpGZRvJcw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars-Bl5_t81uXklo5mpGZRvJcw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3432)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1712)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars-Bl5_t81uXklo5mpGZRvJcw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars-Bl5_t81uXklo5mpGZRvJcw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars-Bl5_t81uXklo5mpGZRvJcw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(AppComponentFactory.java:84)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3425)
    ... 8 more
```

Is this because the OneSignal library is not being included in the release?  I've also seen mention of AndroidX or multi-dex issues.  Here is the android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="15" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:label="WhyBuyCars" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@drawable/whybuycars_icon_512x512">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android-name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" android:glEsVersion="0x00030002" />
    <permission android:name="com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.woodfordgroup.whybuycars.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

And here are my android project properties (target version is 29):

[image]

I also wonder if something went wrong with the inclusion of various libraries while I was installing OneSignal from Nuget.  Here is my list of project references:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to deploy it with debug profile for testing purposes ? Or deploy it to emulator as release profile?

Comment: Did you install OneSignal in both Core and Android ?. You could also need to clean the projects, delete obj* and bin* and try again

Comment: Thanks @Cfun, I can't deploy in debug mode, but I'm running in the emulator in release mode and that's crashing too, so at least there is a pattern now.  It doesn't produce a error report with stack trace though (Pixel 2 emulator, version 28), so I'm trying to see where the issue is and switching up build options.  FabriceT I've installed OneSignal in both, as per their documentation.

Comment: I examined the APK file and saw that the OneSignal dlls were not being included. I assumed they were being excluded because the linker found no use of the dlls in the code of the android project. I added code and then the dlls got included in the APK. I deployed to Google Play and still the same error.

Comment: @Savage I have the same issue, did you find any solution or workaround? or know the cause?

Comment: No luck, sorry. I'm ready to abandon OneSignal and go another route.

Comment: I am also facing this issue for almost a month now, and OneSignal seems not providing any response on it.

Comment: @Savage what alternate you have in mind?

Comment: try add -keep class com.onesignal.** { *; } to proguard configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the proguard file.

```
-keep class com.onesignal.** { *; }
```

Source: See oncky's comment on question.

Comment: I'm using r8. Should I switch to ProGuard or is there something similar for r8?

Comment: Ok, r8 also recognises ProGuard configuration. Need to add a file to the Android solution called `proguard.cfg` (or any name) and in Properties, set type to `ProGuard Configuration` and build to Copy If Newer. Then the problem went away. On another note, I then get a new error with receiving notifications and used the following link to solve that, inserting more bypasses into that new config file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766565/xamarin-forms-android-push-notifications-message-was-successfully-sent-but-the

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, I could receive notifications without crash if disabled R8 code shrinker in settings ( or adding `<AndroidR8ExtraArguments>--no-tree-shaking</AndroidR8ExtraArguments>` after the `<AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>` in android .csproject file).
It seems there's some issue with shrinker for onesignal broadcast receiver class

Comment: I wonder if that reduces the effectiveness of the shrinker though? You would still want most things to be shrunk, and then just handle the special scenarios using oncky's answer.